# How to make a navbar which doesn't push all of my content down?

Tags: html, css

I would like my content to stay in its original place and not pushed by the navbar that I've made on my own.

I am specifying this because the only solutions I have found relate to Bootstrap, which I am not using in this case.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans:wght@400;600;700;800&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans:wght@400;900&display=swap");
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: "Nunito Sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #edf0f1;
    background-color: #131418;
}
li,
a,
button {
    font-family: "Nunito Sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #edf0f1;
    text-decoration: none;
}
header {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px 10%;
}
.logo {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.navbar-brand {
    color: #f94877;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 800;
}
.navbar-brand:before {
    content: "[";
}
.navbar-brand:after {
    content: "]";
}
.linksList {
    list-style: none;
}
.linksList li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}
.linksList li a {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
}
.linksList li a:hover {
    color: #f94877;
}
button {
    padding: 9px 25px;
    background-color: #f94877;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
}
button:hover {
    background-color: #ef5777;
}
#container {
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 2em;
}
#artists {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    place-content: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
.align-self-center {
    -ms-flex-item-align: center !important;
    -ms-grid-row-align: center !important;
    align-self: center !important;
}
.align-items-center {
    -webkit-box-align: center !important;
    -ms-flex-align: center !important;
    align-items: center !important;
}
.flex-wrap {
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap !important;
    flex-wrap: wrap !important;
}
.d-flex {
    display: -webkit-box !important;
    display: -ms-flexbox !important;
    display: flex !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-grid-only@1.0.0/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">expMirror</a>
      <nav>
        <ul class="linksList">
          <li><a href="#">Artists</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Subscribe</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <a href="#" class="cta"><button>Contact</button></a>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      

      <section id="artists">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center align-self-center">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-7 col-md-6 col-lg-7">
              <h1>Welcome</h1>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum voluptates perspiciatis quam harum temporibus labore dolorem ullam nulla cum praesentium? Itaque dolor ipsam aliquid maxime quis, expedita saepe optio harum?</p>
              <p class="mt-3"><a href="#">See more...</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
```

See? I would like my content to be perfectly vertically centered, and not just pushed by navbar.

Comment: add code with your content (html)

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov just edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, your problem can be solved in several ways. Your content is pushed using the `height: 100vh` rule in the `#artists` selector. Because `100vh` is the screen height. One solution would be `height: calc (100vh - 70px)`. Those. you need to subtract the height `header` from the screen height.

This solution will work correctly only in full screen modes.

I can make a second solution with JavaScript, where the `header` height will be automatically calculated.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans:wght@400;600;700;800&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans:wght@400;900&display=swap");
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: "Nunito Sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #edf0f1;
    background-color: #131418;
}
li,
a,
button {
    font-family: "Nunito Sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #edf0f1;
    text-decoration: none;
}
header {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px 10%;
}
.logo {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.navbar-brand {
    color: #f94877;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 800;
}
.navbar-brand:before {
    content: "[";
}
.navbar-brand:after {
    content: "]";
}
.linksList {
    list-style: none;
}
.linksList li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}
.linksList li a {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
}
.linksList li a:hover {
    color: #f94877;
}
button {
    padding: 9px 25px;
    background-color: #f94877;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
}
button:hover {
    background-color: #ef5777;
}
#container {
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 2em;
}
#artists {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    place-content: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    /*height: 100vh;*/
    height: calc(100vh - 70px);
}
.align-self-center {
    -ms-flex-item-align: center !important;
    -ms-grid-row-align: center !important;
    align-self: center !important;
}
.align-items-center {
    -webkit-box-align: center !important;
    -ms-flex-align: center !important;
    align-items: center !important;
}
.flex-wrap {
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap !important;
    flex-wrap: wrap !important;
}
.d-flex {
    display: -webkit-box !important;
    display: -ms-flexbox !important;
    display: flex !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-grid-only@1.0.0/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">expMirror</a>
      <nav>
        <ul class="linksList">
          <li><a href="#">Artists</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Subscribe</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <a href="#" class="cta"><button>Contact</button></a>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      

      <section id="artists">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center align-self-center">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-7 col-md-6 col-lg-7">
              <h1>Welcome</h1>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum voluptates perspiciatis quam harum temporibus labore dolorem ullam nulla cum praesentium? Itaque dolor ipsam aliquid maxime quis, expedita saepe optio harum?</p>
              <p class="mt-3"><a href="#">See more...</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
```

In the second solution, I set `height: 90vh` for the `#artists` of the selector, and `height: 10vh` for `header`. In total, both sealers add up to `100vh`, which is equal to the screen height.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans:wght@400;600;700;800&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans:wght@400;900&display=swap");
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: "Nunito Sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #edf0f1;
    background-color: #131418;
}
li,
a,
button {
    font-family: "Nunito Sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #edf0f1;
    text-decoration: none;
}
header {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px 10%;
    height: 10vh;
}
.logo {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.navbar-brand {
    color: #f94877;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 800;
}
.navbar-brand:before {
    content: "[";
}
.navbar-brand:after {
    content: "]";
}
.linksList {
    list-style: none;
}
.linksList li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}
.linksList li a {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
}
.linksList li a:hover {
    color: #f94877;
}
button {
    padding: 9px 25px;
    background-color: #f94877;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
}
button:hover {
    background-color: #ef5777;
}
#container {
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 2em;
}
#artists {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    place-content: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 90vh;
}
.align-self-center {
    -ms-flex-item-align: center !important;
    -ms-grid-row-align: center !important;
    align-self: center !important;
}
.align-items-center {
    -webkit-box-align: center !important;
    -ms-flex-align: center !important;
    align-items: center !important;
}
.flex-wrap {
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap !important;
    flex-wrap: wrap !important;
}
.d-flex {
    display: -webkit-box !important;
    display: -ms-flexbox !important;
    display: flex !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-grid-only@1.0.0/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">expMirror</a>
      <nav>
        <ul class="linksList">
          <li><a href="#">Artists</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Subscribe</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <a href="#" class="cta"><button>Contact</button></a>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      

      <section id="artists">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center align-self-center">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-7 col-md-6 col-lg-7">
              <h1>Welcome</h1>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum voluptates perspiciatis quam harum temporibus labore dolorem ullam nulla cum praesentium? Itaque dolor ipsam aliquid maxime quis, expedita saepe optio harum?</p>
              <p class="mt-3"><a href="#">See more...</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
```

Solution with calculating the height of the `header` by means of JavaScript.

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', function(e) {
  let header_height = document.querySelector('header').offsetHeight;
  let artists = document.querySelector('#artists');
   
  artists.style.height = 'calc(100vh - '+ header_height + 'px' +')';
   
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans:wght@400;600;700;800&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans:wght@400;900&display=swap");
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: "Nunito Sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #edf0f1;
    background-color: #131418;
}
li,
a,
button {
    font-family: "Nunito Sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #edf0f1;
    text-decoration: none;
}
header {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px 10%;
}
.logo {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.navbar-brand {
    color: #f94877;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 800;
}
.navbar-brand:before {
    content: "[";
}
.navbar-brand:after {
    content: "]";
}
.linksList {
    list-style: none;
}
.linksList li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}
.linksList li a {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
}
.linksList li a:hover {
    color: #f94877;
}
button {
    padding: 9px 25px;
    background-color: #f94877;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
}
button:hover {
    background-color: #ef5777;
}
#container {
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 2em;
}
#artists {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    place-content: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.align-self-center {
    -ms-flex-item-align: center !important;
    -ms-grid-row-align: center !important;
    align-self: center !important;
}
.align-items-center {
    -webkit-box-align: center !important;
    -ms-flex-align: center !important;
    align-items: center !important;
}
.flex-wrap {
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap !important;
    flex-wrap: wrap !important;
}
.d-flex {
    display: -webkit-box !important;
    display: -ms-flexbox !important;
    display: flex !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-grid-only@1.0.0/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">expMirror</a>
      <nav>
        <ul class="linksList">
          <li><a href="#">Artists</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Subscribe</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <a href="#" class="cta"><button>Contact</button></a>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      

      <section id="artists">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center align-self-center">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-7 col-md-6 col-lg-7">
              <h1>Welcome</h1>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum voluptates perspiciatis quam harum temporibus labore dolorem ullam nulla cum praesentium? Itaque dolor ipsam aliquid maxime quis, expedita saepe optio harum?</p>
              <p class="mt-3"><a href="#">See more...</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
```

Comment: Woah, thanks!

Would be great if you give me the second solution with Javascript, even tho this solution does the job perfectly!

Comment: I apologize for the long answer. a lot of work .. i made you a solution with javascript. So that you can understand how it works - run the solution snippet with js, then click in `#artists` and look in the browser object inspector. The value will change dynamically.

Comment: Thank you! I used the second solution, this works great!

Comment: Always happy to help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways to solve your problem.

The first solution i would suggest is by moving the .container upwards by the height of the nav bar. This will stop the nav bar from pushing down your content.

```
.container {
    top: -70px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Another solution would be to change your height of the #artists ID from 100vh to something around 70 - 80vh:

```
#artists {
    height: 75vh;
}
```

If you wanted to bring it closer to the navigation, simply lower the height.